# debugger info & issues

Tags: web, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

complete HTML virgin 3 weeks ago but have managed to stumble along and get my site up and running to an ok standard but im having problems with fb intergration, fb like looks like it should, comments posting as they should but on debug i get the following....

```
Scrape Information

Response Code   200
Fetched URL http://shropshireradio.com/
Canonical URL   http://ShropshireRadio.com/
Object Properties

fb:app_id   149188391870835
og:url  http://ShropshireRadio.com/
og:type website
og:title    Streaming Shropshire DJs
og:image    
og:description  music of all genres under 1 roof
og:updated_time 1331952439
Raw Open Graph Document Information

Meta Tag    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="149188391870835" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:url" content="http://ShropshireRadio.com" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:title" content="Streaming Shropshire DJs" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:description" content="music of all genres under 1 roof" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="http://i1067.photobucket.com/albums/u437/ShropshireRadio/ShropshireRadio.jpg" />
Redirect Path

original    http://shropshireradio.com/
og:url  http://ShropshireRadio.com/
Final URL is in bold (this is the URL we tried to extract metadata from).
```

I can see above that it doesnt look right but cant match it up to my code to see whats wrong!! any help appreciated!! Cheers

I've had to change 2 urls fetched and cononical to post this in my script it is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content attribute for the meta tag with property "og:type" should be something from [this list](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/)  currently you have it as the url for your site.

the prefix attribute of your head tag should be this

```
og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# website: http://ogp.me/ns/website#
```

also, you should change the data-href attribute of your fb:like tag from `http://www.facebook.com/ShropshireRadio.comTeam` to `http://shropshireradio.com/`

Comment: thanks Brandon have now corrected that error report now edited post to show new error report, again any help aprreciated

Comment: it looks like the data-href of your fb:lke tag needs to be fixed.  You currently have "http://www.facebook.com/ShropshireRadio.comTeam"  you probably want "http://shropshireradio.com/"

Comment: thanks, i made a mistake naming my fb page ended up with team at the end, should it point to the website or the fb page?

Comment: you can have it point to either your facebook fan page or your website.  whatever you like (or where eve you would like to drive the most traffic to).  Just make sure that you test your link to make sure it goes to the correct place.

Comment: so the data href is correct in that its pointing to my fb page? if so why am i still getting errors? again thank you for your time its most appreciated

Comment: just remove the prefix attribute from your head tag. try that and lets see how that goes.

Comment: thanks again Brandon, looks like that cleared up most of it, have updated op again 1 last thing by the looks if you could be so kind as to help with it?!? Cheers

Comment: nice one brandon, messed about a bit again think i fixed it, sorry for not replying immediately, thanks so much for the help, wouldnt have done it without you, cheers

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work